# Arrange Radio Button

Tags: html, css, angular

Actually, I want to arrange radio button like image bellow:

[image]

But it become like this

[image]

Here code for your reference

**HTML**

```
<div  class="form-group">
<label *ngFor="let radiobutton of radioItems">
  <input type="radio" name="options" (click)="model.option = radiobutton"
  [checked]="radiobutton === model.option">{{radiobutton}}
</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-group {
        margin: 2px auto;
        width: 12rem;
        position: relative;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        column-count: 2;
        clear: both;
    }
```

Reference [Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-buttons-kaz5nf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use flexbox:

```
.form-group {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 100px;
        // Other properties.
    }
```

Live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-buttons-58ccoi

Comment: adding to this answer: to change number of options in a column change `height` css.

Comment: You're welcome @Pravu. I would wait for other solutions without setting `height`, or any simpler solutions.